# I can't tell in which DB a row is located from just the global identifier

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql, sharding

If I have a `User` table (with a global `id` as primary key) that is sharded across 10 databases (`DB1`-`DB10`) based on the `username`, and another table tries to refer to the `User` table using the `User` table row's global `id`, there is no way for me to know which DB (1-10) that user is located in.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: How did you shard it?  Who designed the system? What RDBMS?  You tagged it as 3 different ones. There's a lot of information missing here...

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Change your sharding scheme so that you shard based on the key you use to look up this data. If it's by ID, always do it by ID, and shard it by ID (DB = ID % 10)
2. Make the primary key of the `User` table the `username`. Enforce its uniqueness and use the `username` as the foreign key in the other tables, not a synthetic identifier.
3. Create a lookup table you can reference which maps `id`s to shards.

Comment: first is not possible because when the user login i can't expect him to type in the global ID.. as for 3, for users that could do the trick. but what if for tables with so many rows that even that lookup table requires sharding? what trick would i use then?

Comment: Unless you get way more than say 10 million users, that user (lookup) table should not be a problem. And even then, the DBMS should be able to handle that. We have tables with a lot more rows than that in a single server (Oracle, PostgreSQL) without problems.

Comment: i'm of course not worried about the user table. say each user has 200 "items" in a row that's already 2 billion rows with just 10 million users.

Comment: Huh? What does that have to do with the lookup table? If each user has 200 items they have 200 items no matter how you look up the foreign key...